# List Generic IEnumerable has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, list, generics

I'm trying to improve my program which currently builds a generic list of strings as follows:

```
 List<string> fileList = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

to a ***different*** generic list which is hopefully more flexible:

```
List<InputFileInfo> fileList = List<InputFileInfo>(Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

 public class InputFileInfo
{
    public string _fullPath { get; set; }
    public string _Message { get; set; }
    public int _RowCount { get; set; }
    public InputFileInfo(string fName)
    {
        _fullPath = fName;
        _RowCount = 0;
        _Message = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Directory.GetFiles returns a string array and I guess my InputFileInfo constructor is not sufficient. Do I need to loop thru a string array and populate List using an .Add method for each element of .GetFiles array or is there a way to populate my new List in one statement like the List of strings?

Comment: Well, a string array is entirely different from a `List<InputFileInfo>`.

Comment: Do you even need a List at all?  I bet you could get by and improve performance by sticking with just IEnumerable<InputFileInfo>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - ideally with [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx):

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                        .Select(name => new InputFileInfo(name))
                        .ToList();
```

If you haven't come across LINQ yet, I *strongly* recommend that you look at it in detail. It's ideal for this sort of thing.

Comment: we need a club "skeet beat me to it" :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Enumerable.Select Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) to convert each string into a InputFileInfo object, and the [Enumerable.ToList Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to turn the resulting IEnumerable<InputFileInfo> into a List<InputFileInfo>:

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Select(fileName => new InputFileInfo(fileName))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var fileInfoList = files.Select(x => new InputFileInfo(x)).ToList();
```

The `Select()` projects each string onto a corresponding object of your type.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or greater you can use LINQ

```
Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(i => new InputFileInfo
(i)).ToList();
```